# Using php variables over more than 2 pages

Tags: php

I have used a form to send two variables from one page to another. Then I wanted the user to be able to click on a link (staying on the website) then once on the third page the variables to still be able to be used.

First page (which works fine):

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Form </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="result.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Then the second page (which displays the variables correctly):

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>
 <a href="name.php" target="_blank">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then when you click on the link from the second to the third (below) it doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Form </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Store the data in a session or in a db and use them whenever and wherever you want

Comment: Sessions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put $_POST['name'] and  $_POST['email']  in session variables.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is:

```
<a href="name.php?email=<? echo $_POST['email'];?>&name=<? echo $_POST['name']; ?>" target="_blank">link</a>
```

On name.php you will have them as $_GET variables

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to use these values on 3rd page only then better to use the above GET method. Otherwise you can put these values in session

Answer (score 1):

Your second (result.php) page should look like this:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email']= $_POST['email'];
?>        
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>
<a href="name.php" target="_blank">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And you third page (name.php) will work when you put it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Form </title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```